# 3-column to matrix using python scripting

Tags: python, bash, matrix

I have a set of data I want to convert into matrix using python.

[column set 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8yDi.png)

and I want to make it into a matrix like this 
[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iysHR.png)

How can I use python or bash script to do this for a larger data set?

Comment: do you know the max length of matrix?

Comment: Hi, the max length of my matrix is inconsistent, therefore I would like a code to be flexible enough that it will read the last number in the first column to be the max length. i,e. it will be 5 in this case.

Comment: Read [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/793796)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using list of list:

```
matrix=[]
for i in xrange(max):
    matrix.append([None]*max)
for x,y,v in inputs:
    matrix[x][y]=v
```

Comment: smart way. I personally prefer native methods like this.